# Spreading quantity over capacity

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Have two dataframes: *machines* and *demand* as follows:

**machines**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

dates = pd.Series([d.date() for d in pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=4, freq='W')])
sites = pd.Series('TH, ID'.split(','))
product = list('AB')
machine = ['M1', 'M2'] # can have multiple machines per site for a product

machines = pd.DataFrame([e for e in itertools.product(dates, sites, product, machine)], 
                        columns=['Date', 'Site', 'Product', 'Machine'])

machines['Capacity'] = np.random.randint(10, 35, size=len(machines))
machines['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(machines.Date).dt.strftime('%Y-%U')

machines.head()
```

**demand**

```
s = 'TH, ID, IN'.split(',')
s = s + s[::-1]

demand_days = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=12*7, freq='D')
demand_days

demand = pd.DataFrame([e for e in itertools.product([d.date() for d in demand_days], s, product)],
                     columns=['Date', 'Site', 'Product'])

demand['Qty'] = np.random.randint(1,50, len(demand))
demand['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(demand.Date).dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
demand.head()
```

merged *groupby* for *demand.Qty* shows:

```
pd.merge(demand, machines[['Week', 'Site', 'Product', 'Machine', 'Capacity']], on=['Week', 'Site', 'Product']).set_index('Week').groupby(['Week', 'Site', 'Product']).Qty.sum()[:5]
```

merged *groupby* for *machine.Capacity* shows:

```
pd.merge(demand, machines[['Week', 'Site', 'Product', 'Machine', 'Capacity']], on=['Week', 'Site', 'Product']).set_index('Week').groupby(['Week', 'Site', 'Product', 'Machine']).Capacity.sum()[:5]
```

How to merge machines and demand and create a unified dataframe such that:

- if demand Qty is greater than Capacity of first machine in a Site,
  the next machine is filled
- if there are no more machines left, the
  last machine takes the remaining load (i.e. is overloaded)
- demand can have extra rows